# Animation on showing up in android

Tags: android

I am trying to perform animation on 4 png images.
I have `drawable` folder in `res` folder,containing the images to be animated and one `animation.xml`

Now my problem is that:when I say `animation.start`
I cannot see anything on the emulator

**my code:**

```
package com.androcles.TreeActivity;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TreeActivity extends Activity {

 private ImageView image1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tree);
   image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   image1.setImageBitmap(null);
   image1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);




final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image1.getBackground();
image1.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        if ( mailAnimation != null )
        {   
            System.out.println("Before Animation Starts...!!!!!");
            mailAnimation.start();
            System.out.println("After Animation Starts...!!!!!");
        }
    }
});
}
 }
```

Comment: This code displays Before Animation starts and After animation starts but does not display animation

Comment: Are you just trying to fade in the image views when the app starts?

Comment: post animation.xml file.

Comment: Try These :: `image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 image1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) image1.getBackground();  mailAnimation.start();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

> ```
>  m_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
>                     getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_animation);
>             m_ivImage.startAnimation(m_animation);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try with these codes.

```
View view;
 view=(Button)findViewById(R.id.continue_but);    // may be image or some thing 


   Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AppActivity.this, R.anim.slide_left); 
         view.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump); 
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```